# rails set default value for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In my first Rails (5) app, I want to set a default value for an association on create. Have read documentation and many questions on SO yet can't find the answer.

I use`after_initialize :set_default_values` and want to set the default for `documenttype`

```
def set_default_values
    unless persisted?
        self.documenttype || 1  if self.documenttype.nil?
        self.dateformat ||= 'dd.mm.yyyy' if self.dateformat.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: you forgot the `=` sign: `self.documenttype ||= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `=` in here:

```
self.documenttype || 1  if self.documenttype.nil?
```

It should be like

```
self.documenttype ||= build_documenttype
```

or for a specific documenttype:

```
self.documenttype ||= Documenttype.find(1)
```

EDIT:
In comment OP mentioned `documenttype` is a `has_one` association.

Comment: adding the `=` sign does not resolve; it then renders an error `Documenttype(#70289997518120) expected, got Fixnum(#70289925178420)`

Comment: So documenttype expect a different type of object(Documenttype) and you are trying to put default value 1, so this error. What kind of variable is `documenttype` ? If can give me some more detail then I might be able to help

Comment: it is an has_one association

Comment: try `self.documenttype ||= build_documenttype` and if it helps then i will update my answer

Comment: and how do I add the specific document type I want as default?

Comment: then maybe something like `self.documenttype ||= Documenttype.find(1)`

Comment: that works! And so does `self.documenttype ||= Documenttype.find_by_name('Unknown')`

Comment: Glad it helped. you can accept and upvote if you want

Comment: change your answer then pls

Comment: Done . Happy coding. :)

Comment: "nothing is impossible if you really try." my motto :-)